# How can I make the VLC History log store more than the last ten?

Tags: video, vlc-media-player, history

By default VLC player only shows the last ten videos under "Media > Open Recent Media"

But what if I'd like to be able to see what I've selected (and choose one of them) from as far back as the last thirty, or even fifty video files? It is such a small amount of data to store, and I'd find it so handy!

Comment: I was also trying to do this at one point and couldn't find a solution. I suspect you will have to modify the source code [VLC media player source code - VideoLAN](https://www.videolan.org/vlc/download-sources.html)

Comment: If I pin VLC to the taskbar and right-click, I get more than 10. This is probably the history by Windows that includes videos that I started from Explorer. The Windows history list length could perhaps be increased, if that helps you.

Answer (score 0):

One way I have found to get more than ten recent media is to go to Media>Open Recent Media>Save To Playlist.

Save the playlist file then open it and it will have up to 30 recent files in the playlist.